# RSS Reader library for local network feeds of different feed formats

Tags: javascript, c#, rss, rss-reader

I need to implement RSS reader that should support feeds, accessible only through local network. We need to support feeds of different formats (RSS 0.91, 1.0, 2.0, other formats support would be a benefit as well).

3rd party libraries like [FeedEk](http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEK/FeedEk.html), [Feednami](https://feednami.com/) etc wouldn't work (since they send requests to some proxy site: query.yahooapis.com or api.feednami.com which actually get XML file from RSS URL and convert it to JSON). Surprisingly, I couldn't find any library that has it's server-side part which can be included into our server product. If someone can recommend the one - it may be a solution.

I could only find an [article](http://www.davidjuth.com/rest-demo-jquery-rss.aspx) suggesting to create own HTTP Handler which just reads RSS from the specified URL and writes it to the output. The problem with it is that feed may have different formats and parsing them is more complex that I would want to make my code.

I came to idea of consolidating different RSS into 2.0 format, maybe with the help of XSLT. I even found an [XSL for converting 1.0 format into 1.1](http://inamidst.com/rss1.1/rss1to1.1.xsl). But not all transformations are available so it seems it's not that common way of doing this.

One more hope was related to .NET [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace. Unfortunately it contains parsers for Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0 formats only. And in addition I need to know in advance which format is it to create appropriate parser, which is not ideal approach - instead it should have automatically detected which format is it if it knows how to parse them.

Any suggestions on how to unify RSS format of local network feeds will be highly appreciated.